# Get form elements by name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, element

I would like to style all of the radio buttons with the same name in a form easily in a nice Prototype or jQuery-style shortcut.

`$('billship').select('name:shipType')` or something like that.

Does such a shortcut for form field names exist?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$('#billship input:radio[name="shipType"]');  
$('input:radio[name="shipType"]', '#billship');
```

Both are equivalent, but the 2nd one performs slightly better and I personally prefer it.

With Prototype, I believe it would look like this:

```
$$('#billship input[type="radio"][name="shipType"]');
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm happy to Cornify this one. :)

Comment: Note, this will not work on IE8 or lower unless you use Prototype 1.7+. You'll have to use 'id' attributes in that case.