# How to get selectbox value with name

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get form elements by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706844/get-form-elements-by-name)

Here's a link i can't get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/PwfzR/3/

Comment: are you wanting the alert to trigger when the person clicks on the input, or begins typing, or submits?

Comment: When the Select Box is onChange

Comment: I posted an answer. I can also save my edit to jsfiddle if you like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you had `input` instead of `select`. Here, I'll post the corrected code. Tell me if this works:

```
 $("select[name='selectbox']").change(function() {
 alert('t');
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
$('input[name="box"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more specific and matches `<input type="text">` elements only:

```
$('input[type="text"][name="box"]');
```

Of course, if you don't want to restrict your matches to `type="text"`, you can use the following code, as [scunliffe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6144/scunliffe) mentions:

```
$('input[name="box"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$("input[name='box']");
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PwfzR/

Comment: This doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/PwfzR/2/

Comment: and this works :) http://jsfiddle.net/PwfzR/4/

Comment: the reason your fiddle is not working is that you have specified this selector `$("input[name='selectbox']")` this implies that and `input` element with the attribute `name='selectbox'` where as actually you had a select element

Answer (score 0):

$('input[name$="box"]').val();

See the full documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Answer (score -2):

If you already know the name of the element just prepend # to the name to select it.

$('#box')
  this will work for any named element.

Comment: That will work only for an element with an `id` of 'box'.

Comment: ah you are right... it is only for IDs... I always use IDs for that very reason.